# 32 bit OpenCL SDK and 64 bit OS ERROR

Tags: windows, windows-8, 64-bit, opencl, 32-bit

Well I have got a 64 bit windows 8 and usually 64 bit OS also support 32 bit software as per microsoft documentation something like emulator WOW64 let it done. But I after downloading OpenCL 32 bit when I tried to install on my 64 bit OS, It says "Set Up will exit" just because of that!

Why is that Sir? Is that anyway to run it?

[It is related to programming because as since OpenCL is related with programming.]

Answer (score 0):

you can refer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/459193/trick-a-32-bit-application-into-running-on-64-bit-system),already superuser community provided detailed answer on it,it works fine .and have you referred installation guide [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdk-for-opencl-applications-installation-guide)

Hope it helped

Comment: @sadaf2605 in general windows 8 64 bit supports 32 bit applications,and for problem of yours did you got any error codes while installation?